# Delete mails with attachment irrespective of the folder they come in

Tags: vba, outlook

I know how to delete mail having attachment as soon as it comes in any specific folder in outlook. I want my macro to delete all mails having attachment irrespective of the folder they come in. In simple words i want to delete mails having attachments as soon as they come in my outlook (in any of the sub folder) Below coding i am using to delete mails from a specific folder(RED CODE). i have few more subfolder under inbox.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.items

Private Sub Application_startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("RED CODE").items

End Sub
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

If item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

    item.Delete

End If

end sub
```

Comment: Use recursion to go to each folder. Check out this resource. http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/looping-recursively-through-folders-and-subfolders/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an array to hold the Items object of each particular folder (IMAPIFolder.Items) - this is done to make sure the variable that raise the events stays alive.

You will then need to hook the ItemAdd even on each Items object.

Comment: thanks Dmitry Streblechenko for looking into this. It would be great if you could give me piece of code.

Comment: I do not have any code that I can share. What are you having problems with?